# Using Regular Expressions in MySql

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to write a sql query which retrieves and matches records from a table with following columns;

```
first_name, second_name, attribute
```

The goal is to write a query, which matches only those records where the column `attribute` is of the following form;

```
<one or more arbitrary character>%<first name>_<second name>%<zero or more arbitrary characters>
```

It should be noted that even the letter cases match for `first_name` and `second_name`. Sample output should look like;

```
first_name  second_name attribute
Vicenta      Kravitz    0%Vicenta_Kravitz%
Shayne     Dahlquist    0R0V331K8Q7ypBi4Az3B6Nm0jCqUk%Shayne_Dahlquist%46E3O0u7t7
 Mikel       Kravitz    PBX86iw1Ied87Z9OarE6sdSLdt%Mikel_Kravitz%W73XOY9YaOgi060r2x12D2EmD
```

As you can see, the cases for the letters in first_name and last_name also match.
Here is my attempt;

```
SELECT first_name,
       second_name,
       attribute
FROM table
WHERE attribute REGEXP  '^.+ CONCAT('%',binary(first_name),'_',binary(last_name),'%').*'
ORDER BY attribute;
```

Since case matching is a requirement, I feel `binary()` function can help. But I am getting following syntax error;

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 35: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_',binary(last_name),'%').*'
    ORDER BY attribute; 
END' at line 10
```

Looking at the manual is not helping a lot. Can I get some feedback what may be going wrong here?thanks

Comment: Why do you duplicate the names in the attributes?

Comment: Parse the "attribute" _before_ storing into the table.  This may lead to multiple rows going into the table, but the SQL will be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concat the hole reg string like

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`first_name` varchar(7), `second_name` varchar(9), `attribute` varchar(66))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`first_name`, `second_name`, `attribute`)
> VALUES
>     ('Vicenta', 'Kravitz', '0%Vicenta_Kravitz%'),
>     ('Shayne', 'Dahlquist', '0R0V331K8Q7ypBi4Az3B6Nm0jCqUk%Shayne_Dahlquist%46E3O0u7t7'),
>     ('Mikel', 'Kravitz', 'PBX86iw1Ied87Z9OarE6sdSLdt%Mikel_Kravitz%W73XOY9YaOgi060r2x12D2EmD')
> ;
> ```

> 

> ```
>     SELECT first_name,
>        second_name,
>        attribute
> FROM Table1
> WHERE attribute REGEXP  CONCAT('^.+%',binary(first_name),'_',binary(second_name),'%.*')
> ORDER BY attribute;
> ```
>
> ```
> first_name | second_name | attribute                                                         
> :--------- | :---------- | :-----------------------------------------------------------------
> Vicenta    | Kravitz     | 0%Vicenta_Kravitz%                                                
> Shayne     | Dahlquist   | 0R0V331K8Q7ypBi4Az3B6Nm0jCqUk%Shayne_Dahlquist%46E3O0u7t7         
> Mikel      | Kravitz     | PBX86iw1Ied87Z9OarE6sdSLdt%Mikel_Kravitz%W73XOY9YaOgi060r2x12D2EmD
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e815e6ac709c4be6ea2ef24090dea80)*

Comment: Appreciate your help. thanks for sharing the dbfiddle link also.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_name, second_name, attribute FROM users
    WHERE attribute REGEXP CONCAT('^.+%',first_name,'_',second_name,'%.*') COLLATE utf8_bin
ORDER BY attribute;
```

or

```
SELECT first_name, second_name, attribute FROM users
    WHERE attribute REGEXP CONCAT('^.{1,}%',first_name,'_',second_name,'%.{0,}') COLLATE utf8_bin
ORDER BY attribute;
```

or

```
SELECT first_name, second_name, attribute FROM users
    WHERE attribute LIKE binary CONCAT('_%\%',first_name,'\_',second_name,'\%%')
ORDER BY attribute;
```